# remove square brackets from string using tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm new to using Tcl and am trying to remove the square brackets from a string using Tcl.

```
set f "abc [def]"
set bracket1 {[}
set bracket2 {]}
    regsub -all "($bracket1) ($bracket2)" $f "" g
    puts $g
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please state the question more clearly; is your snippet an attempt at removing brackets? What does it do, and what should it do?

Answer (score 2):

To remove square brackets from a string, it's easier (and quicker) to use `string map`:

```
set g [string map {{[} "" {]} ""} $f]
```

You *can* use `regsub`, but because `[` and `]` are RE metacharacters *and* RE character-set metacharacters, it can be rather awkward:

```
regsub -all {[][]} $f "" g
# or
set g [regsub -all {[][]} $f ""]
```

Comment: Putting the characters to remove in variables will only make things harder.